# Hiding constraint in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I want a hiding constraint in my application in a programmable way. I have three buttons in this application and I want to hide the middle button. When I am running the application, it is showing some gap between first and third buttons. How can hide that place between two buttons?

Comment: can u show a screenshot ? Please provide more info about the layout/consraint setup you have.

Comment: There a different ways. On way: you could put a constraints with horizontal spacing for button1 to button2, and button2 to button3, and use a Width constraint in button2 that would have value 0 when hidden for instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIView *viewButtonsContainer;
 UIButton *btnFirst=[[UIButton alloc]init];
 UIButton *btnSecond=[[UIButton alloc]init];
 UIButton *btnThird=[[UIButton alloc]init];

[btnFirst setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, viewButtonsContainer.width/2, btnFirst.height)];
[btnThird setFrame:CGRectMake(btnFirst.width, 0, viewButtonsContainer.width/2, btnThird.height)];
```

// this is very simple and basic, I hope it will help